# UITableView Editable from another TableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to add this function in my UITableView : when i click the "+" button (while editing) :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoSegue" sender:self];
```

this perform a segue to another TableViewController with StaticCells where the user  has to add  information about the item such as Name, Date etc etc. 
In the infoSegue controller after the user add information there are 2 buttons : "done" & "cancel".
I am trying to addObjects in the first Controller TableView keeping the information that the user inserted. 
I thought to do it in this way.
Where the user add information (secondController) in the .m file :

```
NSUserDefaults *nameField = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *name = [nameField stringForKey:@"name"];
self.nameTextField.text = name;
```

And where there's the table (firstController.m):

```
NSUserDefaults *nameField = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *name = [nameField stringForKey:@"name"];

self.ingredients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[ingredients addObject:name];
```

the problem is that (obviously) , app crashes because the object can't be nil. 
There's another way? or I just need to fix this way?

Comment: add an exception breakpoint to see where your app crashes.

Comment: crashes when [ingredients addObject:name] because ofcourse if you haven't written anything in the secondViewController for him results = nil.

Comment: so name is nil, isn't it ?

Comment: yep must be nil at the beginning but if the user pres Edit -> Add and fill the blank field. When the user press Done , what he entered must be added as newItem in the table view. The problem is that they are on two different controllers. App crashes because at the beginning there are no items in the tableview so the object name is = nil. I want to avoid this error.

Comment: so check if it equals to nil then don't add name to ingredients. it isn't that simple.

Comment: true! unfortunately when u spend half day doing that , your mind is off!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add the `name` variable, check if name equals to nil, than don't add to the `ingredients` array.